# Checking whether a date is in DST using two boundaries

Tags: c, dst

I am trying to perform a load test and two of the fields requires timestamps. When I recorded the application I noticed that the app server is not using DST and is one hour behind the system's clock. I've got a temporary solution of offsetting by an hour the system's date/time to apply this timestamp.

However, testing will go on throughout the year which will be in and out of DST. So I am thinking of capturing today's date (10/19) and have two boundaries (03/29 and 10/25) with the dates DST coincides with. I've tried to do a simple -

```
if(date > dstLB && date < dstRB)
    do something;
```

With my logic being 10/19 is greater than 03/29 but is smaller than 10/25, however this isn't working (probably obvious to a lot of you!). I was hoping someone here would be able to solve this problem without using any external libraries.

Comment: On the day clocks are set back one hour, you end up with a repeated hour where you can't know if timestamps were from the hour before clocks were adjusted or if they were from the hour after clocks were adjusted (at least, not without additional information like a DST flag). Sane software uses something that isn't effected by DST (or time zones); like UTC; and is therefore immune to problems like this problem (and other problems). Using something sane internally doesn't prevent you from converting to whatever the user's local time happens to be before displaying it.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that DST dates and times vary by time zone, and are usually not set by a fixed date but rather a rule, such as "The last Sunday in October".  Then consider that many time zones change their rules from year to year, sometimes arbitrarily.  If you're not storing and working purely in UTC, then at some point you will *have* to use external information - either from the OS, or from a library.

Comment: You may also want to look at [cctz](https://github.com/google/cctz).  Though it is indeed an external library, it may be just what you need.